# Listing my activity as a Chapter Editor in CV

Tags: cv, editors, books, copy-editing

I am a chapter editor for a particular book. How do I list that in my CV? I see no guidelines particularly stating how to go about stating this.

Please keep in mind that I am not the editor of the book, I am simply an editor for the introductory chapter alongside a few others. There is an author listed for the chapter.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

A section "Other Contributions" or "Service to the Academic Community" would be an appropriate place, provided that you don't have to follow a strict format.

Comment: Is there a particular citation style for chapter editors? I can only find one for chapter authors & book editors.